# Join Two Tables based on a range of dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm struggling to get the below logic.
I have 2 tables.

Table A

```
Request#       ReqDate          Amount    Currency
-----------------------------------------------
REQ1234        2017-01-01       100000    INR
```

Table B

```
ExDate           Conversion      FromCur          ToCur
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-01-03     0.018           INR              USD  
2016-12-20     0.019           INR              USD  
2016-12-21     0.011           INR              USD  
2016-12-22     0.012           INR              USD  
2016-12-23     0.015           INR              USD  
2016-12-24     0.020           INR              USD  
2016-12-25     0.021           INR              USD
```

Here, I need to join on FromCur and Date to get corresponding USD conversionfactor.

However, if the factor for the ReqDate is not available check the previous date, if not available check before that date.

Like wise I need to check 7 days before which is 2016-12-25 and get that factor.

How to do this? 
So the result should be

```
Req#     Date        Conversion     Amount   Currency    ToCur    USDAmt ExDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
REQ1234  2017-01-01  0.021          100000   INR         CAD      2100   2016-12-25
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.conversion
        from b
        where b.fromcur = a.currency and b.date <= a.date
        order by b.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as conversion
from a
```

Comment: This works thanks. However, if the corelated query does not return any row then I need to check for another another, so i should use a case statement?

Comment: @SujithRao . . . You can use `COALESCE()` or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: The correlated sub query can only get one column, what if i need more columns as in the out put shown, where I need to get ExDate,toCur. Thanks.

Comment: @SujithRao . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

For **SQL Server** I suggest an apply operator, and if as you may need NULL returned if one isn't found then use `outer apply`

```
select a.*,rate.conversion 
from a
outer apply (
        select top(1) b.conversion
        from b
        where b.fromcur = a.currency and b.date <= a.date
        -- and b.date > dateadd(day,-7,a.date)
        order by b.date desc
       ) as rate
```

Note if you need to limit how far back you seek a rate use an additional condition in the where clause as suggested above.

You can use a correlated subquery in the select clause, but I recommend using the approach above.

```
select a.*
     , (select top(1) b.conversion
        from b
        where b.fromcur = a.currency and b.date <= a.date
        -- and b.date > dateadd(day,-7,a.date)
        order by b.date desc
       ) as conversion
from a
```

Comment: Thank you. But redshift does not have outer apply.

Comment: I can use left join instaed. This will come handy for me in another scenario. thank you so much.

Comment: If you had originally included redshift as a tag then I  would have proposed syntax for that product. Please use tags  that help us to help you. *Ps. Dont include tags that are not relevant that just confuses us.*